# Query slowness in Delete query with many child table in Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

When i planned to migrate from mysql 5.7 to 8, facing slowness in Delete query for a table which has many child tables.
Even the explain query for that delete query itself slow. It is consistently reproducing. Same issue didn't occur in Mysql 5.7.30.

```
mysql> delete from parent_table_2 where id =1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (4.45 sec)

mysql> explain delete from parent_table_2 where id =1;
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE      | parent_table_2 | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (3.28 sec)
```

Creating a parent with 10000 direct child table with FK ON DELETE CONSTRAINT.

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table_2 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Using a shell script created 10k child tables for that table.

```
#!/bin/bash
MYSQL_USER="your_username"
MYSQL_PASSWORD="your_password"
MYSQL_DATABASE="your_database"

for ((i=1; i<=10000; i++)); do
    TABLE_NAME="table_child_FK_WITH_ON_DELETE_$i"
    QUERY="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME (
        id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        column1 INT,
        column2 VARCHAR(255),
        FOREIGN KEY (column1) REFERENCES parent_table_2(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );"
    mysql -u "$MYSQL_USER" -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" "$MYSQL_DATABASE" -e "$QUERY"
done
```

parent_table_2 has no data at all. Even though delete query fired to this table is facing slowness.

```
mysql> delete from parent_table_2 where id =1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (4.45 sec)
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000119 |
| Executing hook on transaction  | 0.000010 |
| starting                       | 0.000010 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000007 |
| Opening tables                 | 1.876346 |
| init                           | 0.000048 |
| System lock                    | 0.000092 |
| updating                       | 0.000035 |
| end                            | 0.000005 |
| query end                      | 0.000004 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000065 |
| Waiting for semi-sync ACK from | 0.000511 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000015 |
| closing tables                 | 2.571113 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000098 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000056 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.001471 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

Query is taking time in Opening tables and closing tables.

From mysql documentation
Opening tables
The thread is trying to open a table. This is should be a very fast procedure, unless something prevents opening. For example, an ALTER TABLE or a LOCK TABLE statement can prevent opening a table until the statement is finished. It is also worth checking that your table_open_cache value is large enough.

closing tables
The thread is flushing the changed table data to disk and closing the used tables. This should be a fast operation. If not, verify that you do not have a full disk and that the disk is not in very heavy use.

Checked both:
table_open_cache is 524288 and Disk usage usage very minimal.

When tried explain query for that delete, it is also slow.

```
mysql> explain delete from parent_table_2 where id =1;
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE      | parent_table_2 | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (2.77 sec)
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000123 |
| Executing hook on transaction  | 0.000020 |
| starting                       | 0.000016 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000010 |
| Opening tables                 | 1.616061 |
| init                           | 0.000047 |
| System lock                    | 0.000057 |
| end                            | 0.000005 |
| query end                      | 0.000004 |
| waiting for handler commit     | 0.000007 |
| closing tables                 | 1.160547 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000085 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000666 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

When checked other mysql show status parameters, i can find increase in Opened_table_definitions.

```
mysql> show status like "table_open_cache%"; show status like "open_table%"; show status like "opened_table%";
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Table_open_cache_hits      | 0     |
| Table_open_cache_misses    | 0     |
| Table_open_cache_overflows | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name          | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Open_table_definitions | 15659  |
| Open_tables            | 128380 |
+------------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Opened_table_definitions | 0     |
| Opened_tables            | 0     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain delete from parent_table_2 where id =1;
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE      | parent_table_2 | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (3.28 sec)

mysql> show status like "table_open_cache%"; show status like "open_table%"; show status like "opened_table%";
+----------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name              | Value  |
+----------------------------+--------+
| Table_open_cache_hits      | 179997 |
| Table_open_cache_misses    | 1      |
| Table_open_cache_overflows | 0      |
+----------------------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name          | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+
| Open_table_definitions | 15659  |
| Open_tables            | 128381 |
+------------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Opened_table_definitions | 9999  |
| Opened_tables            | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In Mysql 5.7.30 this issue is not occurring and also there is no increase in Opened_table_definitions.

Comment: Probably related to the new implementation of the data dictionary in MySQL 8. What is the use case for 10000 child tables? An obvious solution would be "don't do that."

Comment: Then what will be the suggested maximum child tables that i can have.

Comment: I suggest that you should reconsider an architecture that demands that question.

Comment: @BillKarwin  Do you mean 'an architecture that supports your requirement'?

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I mean this question is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The architecture that requires 10,000 tables is the wrong architecture for whatever problem it seems to solve. If the question becomes, "what is the maximum child tables I an have," then the intention is clearly to continue trying to use that wrong architecture. It's time to take a step back and think about how to solve the project's requirements differently, without using the maximum number of child tables possible.